# PHP SimpleXML add two emelents to string if they do not contain

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I´m trying to get familiar with the PHP `SimpleXML` function and would appreciate a little help. I´m fetching updates to a Call Center received calls and adding only new received calls from the current date to a combined string. I need to run this every 10 minutes via cronjob and let the combined string grow over the day.

Here is the `XML` I´m working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<received>
  <call>
    <countryCode>46</countryCode>
    <phoneNumber>4386541313</phoneNumber>
    <name>Unavailable</name>
    <time>2012-12-05T08:41:29.863Z</time>
  </call>
  ...
</received>
```

What I would like to do is extract all `phoneNumber` and `time` elements with a `foreach` loop and add them as a string to a combined comma seperated string.

The string would looks like this:

```
From the above xml example 4386541313-2012-12-05T08:41:29.863Z
Or phoneNumber-time
```

The comma seperated string would look like this:

```
4386541313-2012-12-05T08:41:29.863Z,1186111311-2012-12-03T08:11:21.561Z,...
```

**But** I only want to add the string to the comma seperated list `IF` the `timestamp` is from the current date.

Here is what I have, but it´s not much and I´m not sure if this is the best way to do what I want:

```
$date_today = date('Y-m-d');
$combined_string = "4386541313-2012-12-05T08:41:29.863Z,1186111311-2012-12-03T08:11:21.561Z";

$received = simplexml_load_file('thexmlfile.xml');

foreach ($received->call->phoneNumber as $phoneNumber) { 
    foreach ($received->call->time as $time) {

        $new_call = $phoneNumber."-".$time;

        if(strpos($new_call,$date_today) !== false)
                    {
            $combined_string = $new_call.",".$combined_string;
        } 
    }
}
```

The above returns a blank page with no errors.

Comment: You're attempting to debug everything at the same time. Why don't you first test whether the loops traverse the XML correctly? Even a simple `echo` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks `Álvaro G. Vicario`. I´ve been using `echo` and `die` to test things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to try something like:

```
foreach ($received->call as $call) { 
    $new_call = $call->phoneNumber . "-" . $call->time;
    if(strpos($new_call,$date_today) !== false) {
        $combined_string = $new_call.",".$combined_string;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks `cjsissingh`, that works much better. it´s actually close to what I had before, but I seem to have made a wrong turn somewhere along the way.<br> The only thing now is that the `IF` statement is not working correctly. If the date today is `2012-11-16` (I´m just using this to test) and the call received is the 16th it is added to the combined string as it should be. If the date today is the 14th it's not added, but if the date is 17th it´s also added but it should not. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try and convert the $call->time into a DateTime object, and just the date_diff function to compare.

http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Thanks. I actually spotted one typo in some code around this one (part of another function) that was causing that issue. Now everything is working just fine :)